# writing a code that checks an ascending sequence only using loops and condition statments only

Tags: c, c89

I was asked to write a code in c language that checks a certain alphabetical order from the input and determines how many "legal" orders are there. the order goes like this: I receive multiple inputs of both numbers(from 1-9) and letters(from A-Z) followed by '@' that determines the end of the input. once a number is received I should check the following letters (meaning if a received the number 3 I should check the next 3 letters and so on), these letters should be organized in ascending alphabetical order. for example ABC3DEF@ (ABC- is not a legal sequence. However, 3DEF is a legal sequence and so in total, I have one legal sequence.)

I tried something but it doesn't work, the output is always 0! (note: I am only allowed to use loops and condition statements, meaning no Array, functions, pointers...). Is there an idea that I am missing? or was my idea wrong?

```
int i, x, sum = 0;
char cha, c = 0;
while((cha = getchar()) != '@') {
    scanf("%d %c", &x, &cha);
    cha = c;
    if(x >= 1 && x <= 9) {
        for(i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            if(c == cha - i) {
                sum++;
            }
            c--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the pattern in that indentation style?

Comment: With `cha=c;` you immediately overwite the value obtained from `scanf`. And from "the output is always 0" - where? The code posted has no output.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito I believe it is inspired by Picasso's Cubism.

Comment: Hallo! Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. This should also show the `#include` files you are using, the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*. Note too that the problem description is confusing. What is the particular C coding problem that you want answered?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons sorry I vandalised it ;(

Comment: See [man 3 getchar](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html). `getchar()` returns type `int` not type `char` and your test for `while((cha = getchar()) != '@')` will fail to detect `EOF`.

Comment: Mixing `scanf` and `getchar` is full of pitfalls for the new C programmer. It would be better to simply use a *state-loop* based on `getchar()` alone and use  a few flags to keep track of whether you are `in` a sequence, whether it is `lgl` and the current `order` of characters read, the `nchr` of characters read and the integer `num` read at the beginning of the sequence. Then it could be a simple matter of `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { if (isdigit(c)) {...} else if (isalpha(c)) {...} else if (c == '@') {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, mixing `scanf` and `getchar` is full of pitfalls. Take your code as an example and your goal to parse the string `"ABC3DEF@"`. Your calls to `getchar` and `scanf` exemplify the problem.

```
while((cha = getchar()) != '@') {
    scanf("%d %c", &x, &cha);
    ...
}
```

When you read `cha`, the test `(cha = getchar()) != '@'` will be TRUE for every character except `'@'`. So for your sequence on first read `cha = 'A'` and `"BC3DEF@"` remains in `stdin`. You then attempt to read with `scanf("%d %c", &x, &cha);` and a *matching failure* occurs because `'B'` is not a valid start of an integer value, and character extraction from `stdin` ceases leaving `'B'` unread in `stdin`. Neither `x` or `cha` are assigned values.

You then attempt:

```
    cha = c;
    if(x >= 1 && x <= 9) {
```

Which sets `cha = 0;` and invokes *Undefined Behavior* by accessing the value of `x` (a variable with automatic storage duration) while the value is indeterminate. See [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2).

So all bets are off at that point. You loop again, this time reading `'B'` with `getchar` and the *matching failure* and all subsequent errors repeat.

Further, the type for `cha` must be `int` as that is the proper return type for `getchar` and necessary to evaluate whether `EOF` has been reached (which you do not check). See: [man 3 getchar](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html)

Instead, eliminate `scanf` from your code entirely and simply loop with:

```
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
       ...
    }
```

(**Note:**, I have used `int c;` where you used `char cha;`)

You can then handle everything else that needs to be done with three primary conditions, e.g.

```
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (isdigit (c)) {              /* if c is digit */
            ...
        }
        else if (isalpha(c)) {          /* if c is [A-Za-z] */
            ...
        }
        else if (c == '@') {            /* if c is end character */
            ...
        }
    }
```

From there you simply define several variable that help you track whether you are `in` a valid sequence, whether the sequence is currently legal (`lgl`), the number of characters read as part of the sequence (`nchr`) and the integer number (`num`) converted at the beginning of the sequence, in addition to keeping track of the previous (`prev`) character, e.g.

```
    char buf[MAXC];
    int c, in = 0, lgl = 1, nchr = 0, num = 0, prev = 0;
```

With that you can simply read a character-at-a-time keeping track of the current "state" of operations within your loop,

```
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (isdigit (c)) {              /* if c is digit */
            if (!in)                    /* if not in seq. set in = 1 */
                in = 1;
            num *= 10;                  /* build number from digits */
            num += c - '0';
        }
        else if (isalpha(c)) {          /* if c is [A-Za-z] */
            if (in) {
                if (prev >= c)          /* previous char greater or equal? */
                    lgl = 0;            /* not a legal sequence */
                prev = c;               /* hold previous char in order */
                if (nchr < MAXC - 1)    /* make sure there is room in buf */
                    buf[nchr++] = c;    /* add char to buf */
            }
        }
        else if (c == '@') {            /* if c is end character */
            /* if in and legal and at least 1 char and no. char == num */
            if (in && lgl && nchr && nchr == num && num < MAXC) {
                buf[num] = 0;           /* nul-terminate buf */
                printf ("legal: %2d - %s\n", num, buf); /* print result */
            }
            lgl = 1;    /* reset all values */
            in = nchr = num = prev = 0;
        }
    }
```

Putting it altogether in a short example that will save the characters for each legal sequence in `buf` to allow outputting the sequence when the `'@'` is reached, you could do something similar to the following (that will handle sequences up to `8191` characters):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 8192   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
                    /*       (don't skimp on buffer size!)           */
int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC];
    int c, in = 0, lgl = 1, nchr = 0, num = 0, prev = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (isdigit (c)) {              /* if c is digit */
            if (!in)                    /* if not in seq. set in = 1 */
                in = 1;
            num *= 10;                  /* build number from digits */
            num += c - '0';
        }
        else if (isalpha(c)) {          /* if c is [A-Za-z] */
            if (in) {
                if (prev >= c)          /* previous char greater or equal? */
                    lgl = 0;            /* not a legal sequence */
                prev = c;               /* hold previous char in order */
                if (nchr < MAXC - 1)    /* make sure there is room in buf */
                    buf[nchr++] = c;    /* add char to buf */
            }
        }
        else if (c == '@') {            /* if c is end character */
            /* if in and legal and at least 1 char and no. char == num */
            if (in && lgl && nchr && nchr == num && num < MAXC) {
                buf[num] = 0;           /* nul-terminate buf */
                printf ("legal: %2d - %s\n", num, buf); /* print result */
            }
            lgl = 1;    /* reset all values */
            in = nchr = num = prev = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** you can adjust `MAXC` to change the number of characters as needed)

Now you can go exercise the code and make sure it will handle your conversion needs (you can adjust the output to fit your requirements). While care has been taken in putting the logic together, any corner-cases that may need to be handled are left to you.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "ABC3DEF@11abcdefghijk@4AZaz@3AbC@" | ./bin/sequences
legal:  3 - DEF
legal: 11 - abcdefghijk
legal:  4 - AZaz
```

or

```
$ echo "ABC3DEF@11abcdefghijk@3AbC@4AZaz@" | ./bin/sequences
legal:  3 - DEF
legal: 11 - abcdefghijk
legal:  4 - AZaz
```

or without a final `'@'` even an otherwise legal sequence will be discarded

```
$ echo "ABC3DEF@11abcdefghijk@3AbC@4AZaz" | ./bin/sequences
legal:  3 - DEF
legal: 11 - abcdefghijk
```

**Note:** if you did want to accept the final legal sequence even though there is no closing `'@'` before `EOF`, you could simply add an additional conditional after your `while` loop terminates, e.g.

```
    /* handle final sequence before EOF */
    if (in && lgl && nchr && nchr == num && num < MAXC) {
        buf[num] = 0;   /* nul-terminate */
        printf ("legal: %2d - %s\n", num, buf); /* print result */
    }
```

With that change the final example above would match the output of the others.

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation. you see, I am new to coding and thanks to you I now understand what "getchar()" is. however, is there another way to identify numbers from the input that can replace "if(isdigit(c))" ?

Comment: if my input of numbers is specified for numbers between 1-9 and I replace the condition to identifying numbers with :** if(c-'0'>=1 && c-'0'<=9)**. would it be possible?

Comment: You would be better doing `if (isdigit (c) && c > '0') num = c - '0';`. The check with `isdigit()` will tell you it is a digit and `c > '0'` will tell you it's `1-9`.

Answer (score 1):

- Every time you test the `while` loop condition, you read one character, and if it is not an `@`, you *discard* it.  Those discarded characters are part of the data you need to parse.
- Every time you call `scanf()` and the next character is a decimal digit or a `+` or a `-`, you parse that and all the following digits as a decimal number, and then read *and ultimately discard* the next character.
- You do not attempt to read any *following* characters at all, nor to test whether they are letters rather than digits.
- If there is no `@` character in the input, and in some cases even if there is one, then the program will never terminate.  To solve this, it should test for `EOF` in addition to testing for `'@'`.  Moreover, to do this properly you must store the return value of `getchar()` as the `int` it is; `char` cannot represent `EOF`.

Basically, almost nothing about the code presented works as described.

Parsers such as you need to write tend to be written explicitly or implicitly as state machines.  You start in some initial state.  You read some number of characters of input, and according to the current state and the input read, you perform an appropriate action, often including changing the current state to a different one.  Lather, rinse, repeat, until a terminal state is reached (which at minimum should be achieved at the end of the input).